# Pandas - Create a new column (Branch name) based on another column (City name)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, city

I have the following Python Pandas Dataframe (8 rows):

```
City Name
     
New York
Long Beach
Jamestown
Chicago
Forrest Park
Berwyn
Las Vegas
Miami
```

I would like to add a new Column (Branch Name) based on City Name as below:

```
City Name       Branch Name

New York        New York
Long Beach      New York
Jamestown       New York
Chicago         Chicago
Forrest Park    Chicago
Berwyn          Chicago
Las Vegas       Las Vegas
Miami           Miami
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()`. City names not in the dictionnary will be kept.

```
df["Branch Name"] = df["City Name"].map({"Long Beach":"New York",
                                         "Jamestown":"New York",
                                         "Forrest Park":"Chicago",
                                         "Berwyn":"Chicago",}, na_action='ignore')
df["Branch Name"] = df["Branch Name"].fillna(df["City Name"])
```

Comment: What does na_action refer to?

Comment: NaNs won't go through the dictionnary